# How can i scroll page to bottom with JS?

Tags: javascript, scroll

How can i scroll page to bottom with JS ? I have problem about it. I need to scroll page to bottom until the load ends. When the page scrolled bottom, pages creates new elements so need to scroll one more time , one more time ... How can i automate it ?

Comment: You can simply do it. `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);`

Comment: May be like `setTimeout( () => window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight), 100);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `element.scrollIntoView()` in order to scroll directly to the element that you want, here is an example you can use

```
 element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
 this.stopScroll();
```

here is a link for documentation:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score -2):

Try with this code to scroll bottom

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
```